# Unity3D: Mathf Lerp too fast when timescale increases

Tags: unity, c#, lerp

I have an image with a fill amount component controlled by a Mathf Lerp. The problem is, the time for completion of the Mathf Lerp function decreases more than expected when the timescale increases.

When the timescale is equal to 2 the function should take half the time to complete but it takes less than that. Any idea why?

```
public static float demolishTime = 6.0f

public void OnClickDemolish()
{
    InvokeRepeating("demolishProgress", 0f, 0.1f);
}

void demolishProgress()
{        
    progress += (Time.deltaTime / demolishTime);
    demolishProgressBar[DemolishManager.demolishState].fillAmount = (float)Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, progress);
    if (progress >= 1) demolishCompleted();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a coroutine scheduled with `InvokeRepeating`, then the repetition frequency is affected by the current timescale. That means the delta-time adjustment in a InvokeRepeating routine is not necessary.

Comment: But I did not made any delta-time adjustment, correct?

Comment: @ClaudioA You did: `progress += (Time.deltaTime / demolishTime);`. Simply change that to `0.1f / demolishTime`. The `0.1f` is the InvokeRepeating factor.